# EB-2 with NIW: application means cannot apply for student visa again?

Tags: student-visa, greencard

I'm thinking of applying for an EB-2 green card with National Interest Waiver. I'm a PhD student at a large research university on an F1 student visa, with a couple of publications and a decent number of people who could write rec letters so I think the application is realistic.

However, I recently talked to a colleague who told me that if I applied for a green card, no matter if it's rejected or accepted, I can't reapply for a student visa again. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I am not an immigration lawyer. I answered this purely based on my interactions with my lawyer in the US.

The fact that an immigrant petition has been filed for you (regardless of whether it was successful or not) will make it difficult for you to get a nonimmigrant visa again in the future.

If the petition has been withdrawn, make sure you can explain very well to the consular officer at your F1 interview about your ties to your home country and how you plan to use your skills in your home country.